# Pyspark read REST API

Tags: python, api, rest, pyspark

It is the first time I am using Pyspark. I would like to create an ETL which extract from the API and put the data into a database in my local environment. But I have an error to call the API as shown below. Any help would be appreciated.
t
t
The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "etl.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = spark.read.format("org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestDataSource").options(**options).load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 184, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o32.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestDataSource. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:679)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:733)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:221)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestDataSource.DefaultSource
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:653)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:653)
    at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:653)
    ... 14 more
```

My code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("{your app name here}").getOrCreate()
uri = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=JPY&limit=30&aggregate=1&e=CCCAGG"
options = { 'url' : uri, 'method' : 'GET', 'readTimeout' : '10000', 'connectionTimeout' : '2000', 'partitions' : '10'}
df = spark.read.format("org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestDataSource").options(**options).load()
df.printSchema()
```

JAVA version:

```
openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this issue was raised due to a missing dependency.
In the code, you mentioned `org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestDataSource` as your `format`, this particular functionality is not inbuild in spark but depends on third party package called [REST Data Source](https://github.com/sourav-mazumder/Data-Science-Extensions/tree/master/spark-datasource-rest)

you need to create a jar file by building the codebase and add it to your spark as follows:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --jars spark-datasource-rest_2.11-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --packages org.scalaj:scalaj-http_2.10:2.3.0
```

Comment: Do you have a jar file for pyspark?